# google appscript to write sheet data to fusion table

Tags: google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

Would someone have examples of a current **Sheet Script** (JScript) that **authenticates and performs read/write** between matching tables in Google **Sheet** and **Fusion**? 
Online sample scripts and documentation all use old authentication or other APIs. 
I'm helping out a local non-profit with a Mapping application that will read data from Google Fusion. The data entry UI is in Google Sheet, so I need to move new records to Fusion, and read Reference tables values from Fusion to Sheet.

- I can't get past setting up authentication. New to this altogether.
- With a variety of field datatypes, and lot's of text fields, I'm sure I need to wrap the field data somehow, unless there is a painless method.

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Comment: please accept the solution below (click the tick mark) if it answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need OAuth for a pure GAS FusionTables project. All you need is to add the API library, and enable it in the [Developer's Console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

You can then execute simple [SQL Statements](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference) like this:

```
FusionTables.Query.sql("INSERT INTO tblId ('fld1', 'fld2') VALUES('x', 'y')")
```

and

```
var vQueryResult = FusionTables.Query.sql("SELECT * FROM tblId WHERE 'fld1'='xyz'");
```

If you know SQL, you will find yourself frustrated by missing basics such as the OR statement, but with a little ingenuity (and using Google's servers to crunch lookup lists in code), you can get most things done.

Comment: @EricS - no problem :) please accept the solution (click the tick mark) if it answers your question